# how to get near records in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

how can we get the nearest records for implementing next and previous record view in sailsjs?

is there any built in method for this?

e.g. if i have retrieved a single record with id=10, how to get the neighbouring records like record with id=9 and id=11.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume your records have either sequential primary Key or a createdAt timestamp. Pick either one of these columns/keys can lets call it REFERENCE_FIELD.

```
Next record = 
Records
.findOne()
.where({'REFERENCE_FIELD' : {'>':CURRENT_RECORD.REFERENCE_FIELD}})
.sort('REFERENCE_FIELD')
.exec();

Previous record = 
Records
.findOne()
.where({'REFERENCE_FIELD' : {'<':CURRENT_RECORD.REFERENCE_FIELD}})
.sort('REFERENCE_FIELD desc')
.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

In a RESTful Sails JS application, we can get the view at `/record/10`. So if you have the previous and next buttons, you just need to link them to `/record/9` and `/record/11` by passing previous and next IDs.

You should also have boundary conditions for first and last page.